# Google Sheets Publish to Web issue with Google Sheets as endpoint for JSON

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-api

I'm using google sheets as a JSON endpoint. I created my google sheets, then clicked File>Publish to web and used the following JSON file: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1ZaufrGyHAfQVwJPbkneBe9mfBsuBwsOvtREBP9PFRL4/1/public/full?alt=json. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but my data is not being pulled into my site.

I also noticed that I cannot change the google link in the share settings to On-the Public Web. It only says "Anyone with a link" can view. Do you know how I can fix this, so my data will be read into my website?

Thanks!

Answer: Needs to be feeds/list, not feeds/cells.

Comment: Why do you mean by data being pulled to your site? Like what are you trying to do? Is there any code you are using to export this? What is the actual mechanism you are using to pull your data?  Are you actually using the sheets api?

Comment: I meant that the website was not reading the google spreadsheet content.  I actually figured it out and it didn't have anything to do with changing the google link in share settings. It had to do with my JSON feeds, which were displaying as cells rather than a list.

Comment: If that is the case could you maybe post how you solved your issue as an answer so other people may benefit from it?

Comment: The JSON feeds could not be retrieved as cells: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/YOURGOOGLESHEETCODE/SHEETPAGENUMBER/public/full?alt=json . It needed to be /feeds/list/

Comment: I created a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), the next time you have to [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) try to leave it as an actual answer instead of leaving a comment or editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I will create a community wiki post for documentation purpose.

As stated by OP the way to solve this is to export the spreadsheet as list feed, so instead of:

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/**cells**/*Sheet_ID*/1/public/full?alt=json

It should be this:

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/**list**/*Sheet_ID*/1/public/full?alt=json

Replacing `feeds/cells` for `feeds/list`.